# autofac owin wep api and signalr

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr, autofac

I am using autofac with web api and now I want to add signalr as well.
My current configuration is as follows

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        // Register your Web Api controllers.
        IoC.Instance.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        IoC.Instance.RegisterWebApiModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        IoC.Instance.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();

        //Set Autofac to be the Dependency Resolver both for Web Api and for SignalR
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer());
        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware,
        // and finally the standard Web API middleware.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer());
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        //Signalr
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            //   map.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubconfig);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
            };
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });

    }
}
```

IoC Class as follows

```
public class IoC : ContainerBuilder
{
    private readonly static IoC _instance = new IoC();
    private static object _lock;
    private IContainer _componentsContainer;
    public static IoC Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }
    public IContainer GetComponentsContainer()
    {
        if (_componentsContainer == null)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_componentsContainer == null)
                    _componentsContainer = this.Build();
            }
        }
        return _componentsContainer;
    }
    public T Resolve<T>() where T : class
    {
        return GetComponentsContainer().Resolve<T>();
    }
    public ILifetimeScope BeginLifetimeScope()
    {
        return GetComponentsContainer().BeginLifetimeScope();
    }
    private IoC()
    {
        _lock = new object();
        ConfigureDependencies();
    }

    private void ConfigureDependencies()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
        this.Register(c => new SqlConnection(connectionString)).As<IDbConnection>().InstancePerRequest();// InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        //Database Connection OrmLite
        OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = SqlServerDialect.Provider;
        //Register Repositories
        this.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>().InstancePerRequest();//.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        // Register Services
        this.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>().InstancePerRequest();//.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        this.RegisterType<TokenService>().As<ITokenService>().InstancePerRequest();//.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }

}
```

As it is obvious I haven't added dependency injection for SignalR. I want to add
in order to have hub constructors like this

```
private readonly ITokenService _tokenService;
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _hubLifetimeScope;



    public JobHub(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        // Create a lifetime scope for the hub.
        _hubLifetimeScope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope();
        // Resolve dependencies from the hub lifetime scope.
        _tokenService = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<ITokenService>();
    }
```

Any Ideas on how to do this?

Comment: This question is related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064608/autofac-signalr-with-owin-getting-reference-to-the-containerbuilder but I can't find out how to combine these two

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation I found the Solution.
In IoC Class and in method `ConfigureDependencies()` I added the following line at the end `this.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`.
The Configuration method in StartUp now is as follows

```
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        // Get your HttpConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
        // rather than using GlobalConfiguration.

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        //HubConfiguration
        var hubconfig = new HubConfiguration();
        // Register your Web Api controllers.
        IoC.Instance.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        IoC.Instance.RegisterWebApiModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        IoC.Instance.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();

        //Set Autofac to be the Dependency Resolver both for Web Api and for SignalR
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer());
        hubconfig.Resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer());
        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware,
        // and finally the standard Web API middleware.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer());
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        //Signalr
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            map.RunSignalR(hubconfig);
        });

    }
```

And now the tricky thing
My hub Constructor has to become like this

```
 public JobHub(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        // Create a lifetime scope for the hub.
        _hubLifetimeScope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest");
        // Resolve dependencies from the hub lifetime scope.
        _tokenService = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<ITokenService>();
    }
```

I don't how how that thing worked, but it worked. Any suggestions whether this is good or bad configuration are welcome!

Comment: Finally, this actually works. I wish I could just use normal DI instead of having to use the resolver like this, but I'm glad it works and isn't creating excessive overhead. Great job, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Startup.cs` should look like this prior to custom integration

```
  public class Startup
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
      var config = new HubConfiguration();

      // Register your SignalR hubs.
      builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

      // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
      var container = builder.Build();
      config.Resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);

      app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
      app.MapSignalR("/signalr", config);
    }
  }
```

Check out the docs on Autofacs site for more info:
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/signalr.html#owin-integration

Comment: I changed slightly my configuration and now it works but I have one problem. I have various services in my webapi project that are defined as perHTTPRequest like this this.RegisterType<TokenService>().As<ITokenService>().InstancePerDependency(); I want to use services like this in my bub constructor so I use something like this  _hubLifetimeScope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope(); _tokenService = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<ITokenService>();  I get an error saying No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested

Comment: It's more that it's on the docs? And at the end of the day it's compiled to the same thing so no need to get too picky on an answer a year old